# Cron not running jobs - No MTA installed

Tags: brightness, cron, mta

I am a completely newbie in Ubuntu/Linux.
I am trying to get some scheduled tasks, but no success until now.
I am running Ubuntu 16.04

I am trying to use `cron` to fix the brightness of the screen. I am using this code:

```
56 * * * * /usr/bin/xrandr --output HDMI1 --brightness 0.1 # JOB_ID_7
```

The code is running OK on terminal (without the minutes and ***), but not as cron scheduled task.

I've tried also with relative patch (withouth `/usr/bin/`).

When looking at `syslog`, I've seen that:

```
Dec 10 10:56:01 LIQ03 cron[634]: (liq03) RELOAD (crontabs/liq03)
Dec 10 10:56:02 LIQ03 CRON[3586]: (liq03) CMD (/usr/bin/xrandr --output HDMI1 --brightness 0.1 # JOB_ID_7)
Dec 10 10:56:02 LIQ03 CRON[3585]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

So, I understand I have no MTA installed, which I don't know how to install... Any advice?

---

I have installed postfix to see if now the task runs OK, but no chance. The screen is not dimmed anyway.
So, I am thinking that, anyway, the task should run even if postfix is not installed...

`/Var/log/syslog` reports that:

```
Dec 10 11:43:01 LIQ03 cron[634]: (liq03) RELOAD (crontabs/liq03)
Dec 10 11:43:01 LIQ03 CRON[5487]: (liq03) CMD (/usr/bin/xrandr --output HDMI1 --brightness 0.1 # JOB_ID_7)
Dec 10 11:43:01 LIQ03 postfix/pickup[5391]: 1EB7C1611FE: uid=1000 from=<liq03>
Dec 10 11:43:01 LIQ03 postfix/cleanup[5491]: 1EB7C1611FE: message-id=<20161210104301.1EB7C1611FE@LIQ03.homestation>
Dec 10 11:43:01 LIQ03 postfix/qmgr[5392]: 1EB7C1611FE: from=<liq03@LIQ03@liq03.com>, size=622, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 10 11:43:01 LIQ03 postfix/error[5493]: 1EB7C1611FE: to=<liq03@LIQ03@liq03.com>, orig_to=<liq03>, relay=none, delay=0.05, delays=0.03/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (liq03.com)
Dec 10 11:43:01 LIQ03 postfix/cleanup[5491]: 28D271630F8: message-id=<20161210104301.28D271630F8@LIQ03.homestation>
Dec 10 11:43:01 LIQ03 postfix/qmgr[5392]: 28D271630F8: from=<>, size=2561, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 10 11:43:01 LIQ03 postfix/bounce[5494]: 1EB7C1611FE: sender non-delivery notification: 28D271630F8
Dec 10 11:43:01 LIQ03 postfix/qmgr[5392]: 1EB7C1611FE: removed
Dec 10 11:43:01 LIQ03 postfix/error[5493]: 28D271630F8: to=<liq03@LIQ03@liq03.com>, relay=none, delay=0.01, delays=0.01/0/0/0.01, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (liq03.com)
Dec 10 11:43:01 LIQ03 postfix/qmgr[5392]: 28D271630F8: removed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you experience is not the missing MTA, which just disables `cron` to send mails.

The reason that your cronjob is not executed is, that it is run in a different environment than your X session and therefore the cronjob does not have access to the screen.
What you need inside the cronjob is the information about which display `xrandr` should use and the authority to use the display specified. Normally you can use the following in your `crontab` to make it work.

```
56 * * * * XAUTHORITY="/var/run/lightdm/root/:0" /usr/bin/xrandr --display :0 --output HDMI1 --brightness 0.1 # JOB_ID_7
```

You might have to change the content of the `XAUTHORITY` variable depending on your display manager and configuration.
Maybe easiest way to find that is to run the following command and look for the string after `-auth`.

```
user@host:~# ps aux | grep Xorg
root      2604  1.4  3.0 265236 44960 tty7     Ssl+ 12:48   0:00 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
```

Comment: Great, it works now!!! In my case it was the same content for Xauthority, so it runs perfectly now!!